# C# ICryptoTransform error : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.'

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have this exception
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.'
when using this code.

The encryption seems working but an error occured during decryption with this code:

> byte[] result = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, read);

I'm not sure how to use TransformFinalBlock and TransformBlock
Do you have an example wihtout using CryptoStream ?

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks

```
using (Stream input = new FileStream(file1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (Stream output = new FileStream(file2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                    {
                        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                        aes.KeySize = 256;
                        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                        int _keySize = aes.KeySize / 8;
                        aes.BlockSize = 128; 
                        int IV_SIZE = aes.BlockSize / 8;
                        aes.IV = iv;

                        using (var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("password", salt, 15000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
                        {
                            aes.Key = key.GetBytes(_keySize);
                        }

                        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                            int read = 0;
                           
                            byte[] transformed = new byte[10000];
                            while ((read = input.Read(buffer,0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                byte[] result =  encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, read);
                                output.Write(result, 0, result.Length);                                
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                    output.Flush();
                }
            }


            // ****

            using (Stream input = new FileStream(file2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (Stream output = new FileStream(file3, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                    {
                        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                        aes.KeySize = 256;
                        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                        int _keySize = aes.KeySize / 8;
                        aes.BlockSize = 128;
                        int IV_SIZE = aes.BlockSize / 8;
                        aes.IV = iv;

                        using (var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("password", salt, 15000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
                        {
                            aes.Key = key.GetBytes(_keySize);
                        }

                        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                            int read = 0;

                            byte[] transformed = new byte[10000];
                            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                byte[] result = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, read);
                                output.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    output.Flush();
                }
            }
```

Comment: `TransformFinalBlock` is not meant for piecemeal encryption, as it also performs the padding. For Pete's sake, the whole idea of the cryptography package in Microsoft / .NET is stream oriented. File handling is stream oriented. Use streams! I recommend output streams for encryption and input streams for decryption.